# How to properly import corine landcover 2012 (vector file) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, style, land-cover

I'm fairly new to QGIS (using version 2.18.25), so I may be missing something quite basic. I'm using the Corine landcover (clc12_Version_18_5.gdb) in my project. It's a very large dataset (3GB) so it takes time to render but does eventually in default single colour.

However when I add the legend entries (properties > style > load style > clc_legend) associated with the landcover types the layer fails to render.

Do I need to complete another process for this to work or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily fix this. The error is within the given style file. It classifies through a not existing field. Just change the `column` from `code_00` to `code_12`. Then wait some minutes until its loaded.

[image]

[image]

voila:

[image]

Btw. the latest QGIS version is 3.4 https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html in case you want to update. Pretty cool new stuff in there.